# Access the containing object in a constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, this

I want to access the parent object when calling a function contained inside that object as a constructor. See this example:

```
var users = {
    // The count of users
    count: 0,

    // Naturally _this is undefined
    _this: this,

    // Constructor function
    CreateUser: function (name, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;

        // Is this the only way to access the containing object?
        users.count++;
    },

    getCount: function () {
        return this.count;
    },
};
```

If I try to invoke the `CreateUser` function as a constructor, then `this` will be a reference to the blank object that the `new` operator created. See this:

```
var user = new users.CreateUser('Rick', 'rick@example.com')
```

How can I access the `users` containing object in this case without explicitly referring to it?

Comment: Are you asking about a static property?

Comment: @Dexygen this is different, since here I call my function as a _constructor_, so `this` is overriden by the mechanics of `new` in the calling context.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with explicitly referencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is a **static property**, which are still to come in JS. 
It is an experimental feature though.

Currently:

> [Static (class-side) data properties and prototype data properties must be defined outside of the ClassBody declaration:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties)

```
Rectangle.staticWidth = 20;
Rectangle.prototype.prototypeWidth = 25;
```

Since what you do here is somehow similar to [Joshua Bloch's idea of a static factory method](https://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883) or [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in general, it makes sense to move `new` keyword up to *CreateUser* method of *users* object. 
By doing so you can use closure to save the reference to *users* object, implement nested constructor function and invoke it with `new` keyword.

Working example:

```js
var users = {
    count: 0,

    CreateUser: function (name, email) {
        var self = this;
        const createUser = function(name, email) {
              this.name = name;
              this.email = email;
              self.count++;
  
        }
        return new createUser(name, email)
    },

    getCount: function () {
        return this.count;
    },
};
var user = users.CreateUser('Rick', 'rick@example.com')
console.log(user)
console.log(users.getCount())
users.CreateUser('Morty', 'morty@example.com')
users.CreateUser('Jerry', 'apples@example.com')
console.log(users.getCount())
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as an explicit parameter.

```
var users = {
    count: 0,
    _this: this,

    // Constructor function
    CreateUser: function (name, email, parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;

        // Is this the only way to access the containing object?
        parent.count++;
    },

    getCount: function () {
        return this.count;
    },
};

var user = new users.CreateUser('Rick', 'rick@example.com', users);
```

Comment: I suppose that Javascript does not have any knowledge of the upward relationship unless mentioned explicitly. Is this the _only_ way of accessing the parent container then?

Comment: That's correct. The only thing that's passed automatically is `this`, and in the case of a constructor that refers to the object being constructed, not the containing object.

Comment: Another way of doing it would also be to define `users.CreateUser.prototype.container = users` but it looks ugly since every instance of the constructor will also inherit that property. What do you think?

Comment: I assumed this was a simplification and it's not always the same containing object.

Comment: No that's alright. I also never mentioned that the containing object was supposed to be the same.

Comment: In that case `users.count++` is a fine solution.

Comment: Or better yet, put everything in a separate file and import it using the `as` keyword to specify a containing object when the module is imported.